# How to update specific key-value pair in a multi-dimensional json array for setState?

Tags: reactjs, setstate

Below is my state json array that handles the data and page configuration.

```
   {
        auth: {
            profile: null,
        },
        model: {
            data: null,
            error: null,
        },
        pageConfig: {
            hasHeader: true,
            loader: {
                isLoaderActive: true,
                message: 'Loading...'    
            },
            alert: {
                type: null,
                message: null
            },
            redirect: {
                url: '/',
                data: null
            },
        }
    };
```

For now, what's working on my side is updating the model.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, model: data }));
```

Easy because it's only working on a simple array but I would like to ask for guidance on how to update specific key-value pair like the isLoaderActive while maintaining other pairs.

TYIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ES6 spread operator

```js
const state = {
  auth: {
    profile: null,
  },
  model: {
    data: null,
    error: null,
  },
  pageConfig: {
    hasHeader: true,
    loader: {
      isLoaderActive: true,
      message: 'Loading...'
    },
    alert: {
      type: null,
      message: null
    },
    redirect: {
      url: '/',
      data: null
    },
  }
};

const newState = {
  ...state,
  pageConfig: {
    ...state.pageConfig,
    loader: {
      ...state.pageConfig.loader,
      isLoaderActive: false
    }

  }
}

console.log(newState)
```

Or use Lodash.set

```js
const state = {
  auth: {
    profile: null,
  },
  model: {
    data: null,
    error: null,
  },
  pageConfig: {
    hasHeader: true,
    loader: {
      isLoaderActive: true,
      message: 'Loading...'
    },
    alert: {
      type: null,
      message: null
    },
    redirect: {
      url: '/',
      data: null
    },
  }
};

const newState = _.set(state, 'pageConfig.loader.isLoaderActive', false)
console.log(newState)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```